# Laravel 3 - Eloquent save() is saving wrong value over and over

Tags: mysql, payment-gateway, eloquent, laravel-3

I'm going to do my best to explain my situation. Sorry if it doesn't make sense, it really doesn't make sense in the first place.

I have an application that utilizes Laravel 3. I have a model name Receipt that contains payment history from transactions with a payment gateway. Each time a person pays for something a receipt entry is added to the database.

**Receipt Schema**:

```
public function up() {
    Schema::table('receipts', function($table) {
        $table->create();
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('individual_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('transaction_id')->unsigned();
        $table->decimal('amount', 6, 2);
        $table->string('account_number', 8)->nullable();
        $table->string('category', 255)->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
...
```

**Receipt Controller Snippet**

```
...
if ($response->approved) {                
    $r = new Receipt();
    $r->individual_id = $response->customer_id;
    $r->transaction_id = $response->transaction_id;
    $r->amount = $response->amount;
    $r->account_number = $response->account_number;
    $r->category = $response->description;
    $r->save();

    $url = URL::to_action('receipt@history', array($response->transaction_id));
} else {
...
```

My issue is that the transaction_id is not saving the correct value. I have verified that the Payment Gateway response is found in the returned $response->transaction_id property, but what is saved to the DB field is incorrect. For instance, let's say the payment gateway $response->transaction_id is 5879971244... What is saving to my DB is 4294967295 for every transaction ID. It's like I have a setter method for this field but I do not.

If I were to hardcode an arbitrary value to $r->transaction_id such as 1234567890 and then $r->save() it would save fine, just not the value from the $response object.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Int field only allows up to 4294967295 which is what is storing in my DB. I changed the field to bar a varchar. Problem solved!